# VS Dev Server with PayPal

Tags: visual-studio-2015, paypal, paypal-sandbox, cassini, cassini-dev

I've got a client.  We are trying to get their ecommerce system to go out to an out to paypal to process the credit card orders.  I've done this in the past, but it was a few years ago.  Their server is an iis server onsite with an ibm midrange backend.  Right now, I am hooking the front end code into the paypal.  I am using the paypal button that opens a window to the paypal system.  I'm using Visual studio 2015.  I have ssl enabled.  I am connecting to the site via the https url in the project properties.  Firefox complains about there being a self signed certificate, but edge and chrome do not.

When I click on the button to open the PayPal checkout window, the window opens and then immediately.  There is a small message that comes up and if i run click the button enough times, I can see that there is a message saying that the system is not being called from a secure site.  The site is running from an https localhost on a non standard port.  I think I have my client id for the sand box listed properly.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to get this working for the sandbox.  any help is appreciated.

TIA.
Wally

Comment: I have resolved this issue.  Still not quite sure what it was beyond some encoding may have messed things up.  very frustrated, but glad it is working now.

Comment: One side note, I realize that providing too much information back can cause security issues.  It would have been nice to have gotten some type of information regarding the  error that was occurring instead of the sandbox window immediately closing.  Just a suggestion for anyone from paypal reading this.  :-)